# Subscribe collection based on url parameters in meteor

Tags: meteor

I am trying to achieve a dynamic subscription of collection data based on the parameter in the url.

On Client side, I have the following subscription code in main.js file.

```
cSubscribe  =  Meteor.subscribe('cPublish', Session.get('param1'));
```

On Server,  I have the following publish code in main.js file.

```
Test = new Meteor.Collection('test');

Meteor.publish('cPublish', function(param1) {

    return Test.findOne({_id: param1});        

});
```

In the router, I am setting the url parameter value in the Session, `Session.set('param1', value);` and when I try `cSubscribe.ready()`, it is returning false. Until the subscription is ready I am showing a loading template.

The route snippet,

```
'/test-url/:value': function(value) {

    Session.set('param1', value);

    if (cSubscribe.ready()) {
        //some code
    } else {
        return 'loading';
    }

}
```

What is wrong with the process ? Is there any better way of achieving dynamic subscription ?

Answer (score 1):

First, I hope, you use `iron-router` (-:

In router, for example, in onBeforeAction() you have to set `Session.set('param1', value);`

Then on client try to use smth like this:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  Deps.autorun(function() {
    var param = Session.get("param1");
    if(param) {
      cSubscribe  =  Meteor.subscribe('cPublish', param);
  });
});
```

In other words, you have to **resubscribe** after url changed.

Comment: I am actually using the 'router' package. Is it possible with that package?

Comment: I don't know... I think the answer is yes, if can parse url. You have to parse url, fetch param and set Session variable. `Deps.autorun` block the same

Comment: Have added the router code. putting the subscribe code in Deps is giving me an error, 'Uncaught ReferenceError: cSubscribe is not defined'.

Comment: You could try storing cSubscribe in a session variable rather than a normal variable, so that the route function will re-run after the autorun sets `cSubscribe`, and modify your route function accordingly (`cSubscribe = Session.get("cSubscribe");` `if (cSubscribe && cSubscribe.ready()) ...` Nevertheless, iron-router has the exact functionality you're implementing built-in.

Comment: I think iron-router has a dependency on blaze, which is preventing me from using it. Else I will have to rework all the code for blaze compatibility.

Comment: @Anoop: you should rather use an old version of Iron Router than the `router` package. Old router is deprecated and won't be updated, so at one point or another you'll need to switch for the new one. It's better to get used to the new API sooner than later.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the replies. Iron Router it is.